# Why does if statement not work properly inside for loop?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I have an array to be classified by same value..

```
int[] clusters= 0    1    2    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    2    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
int[] clusterDistinct = 0 1 2
```

It is fine using code below, but on last statement (if statement) inside for loop does not print. I don't know whats wrong with my code

```
private void autoClustering(int[] clusters) {
    int[] clusterDistinct = getClusters(clusters);

    for (int i = 0; i < clusterDistinct.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("\nCluster " + clusterDistinct[i]);
        for (int j = 0; j < clusters.length; j++) {
            if (clusters[j] == clusterDistinct[i]){
                System.out.print(j+",");
            }
        }
    }
}

private int[] getClusters(int[] clusters) {
        ArrayList<Integer> klaster = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < clusters.length; i++) {
            boolean isDistinct = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (clusters[i] == clusters[j]) {
                    isDistinct = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!isDistinct) {
                klaster.add(clusters[i]);
            }
        }

        int[] clusterDistinct = new int[klaster.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < clusterDistinct.length; i++)
            clusterDistinct[i] = klaster.get(i).intValue();
        return clusterDistinct;
    }
```

Here is output.. if statement does not working (not print) on last cluster.
cluster 2 (last statement) not print, it should print `2,25` but why not print anything?

```
06-10 20:38:34.204: I/System.out(10634): Cluster 0:
06-10 20:38:34.204: I/System.out(10634): 0,
06-10 20:38:34.204: I/System.out(10634): Cluster 1:
06-10 20:38:34.204: I/System.out(10634): 1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,
06-10 20:38:34.204: I/System.out(10634): Cluster 2:
06-10 20:38:34.204: D/BRCM_EGL(10634): eglMakeCurrent(NULL) Thread: 10634
06-10 20:38:34.204: D/BRCM_EGL(10634): eglDestroySurface() surface: 0x4d4beb30, android window 0x4d4be420, Thread: 10634
```

Comment: How is it not printing? It is.... 1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50

Comment: What are you "Expecting" under cluster 2?

Comment: @Tukajo He is expecting the indices of the values that are 2...ie:  2, 25

Comment: First thing that I want to ask tho is, you have two variables (clusters and clusterDistinct (which you get from some method). Are they identical? Do they have the same length?

Comment: @Carine I see. Yeah the only relevant info left out is how cluster and clusterDistinct work/their elements and size what not.

Comment: Tried it on eclipse on a simple Java class (without Android) and it seems to be returning all the output correctly.

Comment: Also, consider using HashSet<Integer> instead of ArrayList<Integer> (doesn't allow duplicates) or using the "contains" method in ArrayList

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Print a newline character `\n` after your loop to flush the output buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Both of your `System.out.print()`s are working fine. Just one is a `System.out.println()` and the other a `System.out.print()`.

Edit:
I am not sure I understand what you are asking here. Your code is too vague/little to discern the issue. Show us your `getClusters` method as well as some other useful code please.

Comment: He wonders, why there is no output of the indices under *"Cluster 2"*.

Comment: I realize that now. This post was made under his initial post before many edits and much information was added. @Tom